# dropping a very annoying trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am stuck in a very unusal problem. There's one trigger I'd like to drop. Now when I drop it, it is dropped successfully.

```
drop trigger HRCS.hr_external_salary_in_trigger
```

But when I run this command then I can see the trigger again:

```
select * from all_triggers where trigger_name like '%external%'
```

I can see this trigger in UI of PLSQL developer with red x on its head. Now when I try to delete it from left click menu then I get this error:

```
Error dropping HRCS.hr_external_salary_in_trigger
ORA-04080: trigger 'HR_EXTERNAL_SALARY_IN_TRIGGER' does not exist
```

Never saw this kind of behavior. Something which I deleted is still there but the program says it doesn't exist while showing it. o_O

How can I get rid of this undesirable annoyance

Comment: Is `HRCS` your current schema? What is the value of the `owner` column your `select from all_triggers` statement returns?

Comment: yes I have tried to delete from hrcs as well as from system

Comment: please provide the result of the `select * from all_triggers where trigger_name like '%external%'` ,specifically `owner` column

Comment: owner: hrcs, trigger_name: hr_external_salary_in_trigger, trigger_type: after each row, triggering_event: insert, table_owner_ hrcs, base_object_type: table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem

I used quotation marks as in:

```
drop trigger HRCS."hr_external_salary_in_trigger"
```

and it was dropped, finally.

Thanks all for replies :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the dependencies of that trigger using,

```
select * from dba_dependencies;
```

Find out if there are any dependencies or not. Check if you have created a synonym for that trigger.